# How to prove that $ E:=ABC D $ is also positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quadratic-forms

Now I think this is true:

> Let $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ be symmetric, positive definite matrices and suppose that $E:=ABCD $ is symmetric. 
>   How might I prove that $E$ is also positive definite?

the similar question  can see:
 [How to prove that $D := ABC$ is also positive definite?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/377377/how-to-prove-that-d-abc-is-also-positive-definite)

@Landscape  this not true, 
Really? Thank you everyone

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot prove it, because there is a counterexample. Let

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
 58 & 50 & 30 \\
 50 & 66 & 38 \\
 30 & 38 & 22
\end{bmatrix}, \quad B = \begin{bmatrix}
 8 & 6 & 8 \\
 6 & 5 & 4 \\
 8 & 4 & 65
\end{bmatrix}, \quad C = \begin{bmatrix}
 34 & 26 & 46 \\
 26 & 56 & 52 \\
 46 & 52 & 83
\end{bmatrix}, \quad D = \begin{bmatrix}
 \frac{176398144863}{734764024} & \frac{2084349747}{734764024} & -\frac{401393975}{91845503} \\
 \frac{2084349747}{734764024} & 123 & 74 \\
 -\frac{401393975}{91845503} & 74 & 45
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Then
$$ABCD = \begin{bmatrix}
 \frac{3747748968739763}{91845503} & \frac{4372037328164921}{91845503} & \frac{2546983749851550}{91845503} \\
 \frac{4372037328164921}{91845503} & \frac{5099682487522571}{91845503} & \frac{2970895299665430}{91845503} \\
 \frac{2546983749851550}{91845503} & \frac{2970895299665430}{91845503} & \frac{1730738016057502}{91845503}
\end{bmatrix}.$$

$A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ are symmetric positive definite, while $ABCD$ is symmetric, but not positive semidefinite (the determinant of the principal leading submatrix of order $2$ is $-2.82211 \cdot 10^{11}$).

This was generated by few runs of the Mathematica code:

```
RandPDM[n_] := Module[
   {tmp},
   While[True,
    tmp = RandomInteger[7, {n, n}];
    If[Det[tmp] != 0, Break[]]
    ];
   Return[Transpose[tmp].tmp];
   ];
M1 = RandPDM[3];
M2 = RandPDM[3];
M3 = RandPDM[3];
M4 = RandPDM[3];
M4[[1, 1]] = a;
M4[[1, 2]] = b; M4[[2, 1]] = b;
M4[[1, 3]] = c; M4[[3, 1]] = c;
M4[[2, 2]] = d; M4[[2, 2]] = d;
M4[[2, 3]] = e; M4[[3, 2]] = e;
(M = M1.M2.M3.M4) // MatrixForm
sol = FindInstance[{
   Transpose[M] == M,
   a > 0, Det[M4] > 0, Det[Take[M4, 2, 2]] > 0
   }, {a, b, c, d, e}]
(M4 = (M4 /. sol[[1]])) // MatrixForm
(M = (M /. sol[[1]])) // MatrixForm
all = {M1, M2, M3, M4, M};
Map[MatrixForm, all]
Map[PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ, all]
```

The line `Map[MatrixForm, all]` outputs all five (the above are a minor edit of such output with `TeXForm` instead of `MatrixForm`), while the last line checks their positive definitess, with the output

```
{True, True, True, True, False}
```

In case you want to test these matrices for yourself, here is the Mathematica output for them:

```
M1 = {{58,50,30},{50,66,38},{30,38,22}};
M2 = {{8,6,8},{6,5,4},{8,4,65}},{{34,26,46},{26,56,52},{46,52,83}};
M3 = {{176398144863/734764024,2084349747/734764024,-(401393975/91845503)},{2084349747/734764024,123,74},{-(401393975/91845503),74,45}};
M4 = {{3747748968739763/91845503,4372037328164921/91845503,2546983749851550/91845503},{4372037328164921/91845503,5099682487522571/91845503,2970895299665430/91845503},{2546983749851550/91845503,2970895299665430/91845503,1730738016057502/91845503}};
```

Hopefully, I didn't mess up these while editing. Just in case, I'll keep Mathematica running with the above solution for few more hours, in case you have some questions.

Comment: A smaller counterexample could be {{1,-2},{-2,5}}; {{5,-2},{-2,1}}; {{2,3},{3,5}}; {{7,-7},{-7,8}}, product of which (in the given order) is {{-7,14},{14,-29}}

Comment: But where is the fun in that? :-) Just kidding; it's a really nice and simple example.